# Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.RTD is not recalculated when double click on the function

Tags: excel, vba

I m writing an Excel plugin that uses a custom written `RTD Server` and to call `ConnectData` function of that RTD Server, I use `Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.RTD` in VBA passing required parameters to the function.

All the functionality of RTD is working fine, but if I double-click and press enter on an RTD function in Excel (In other words, when parameters do not get changed), `Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.RTD` is called but `ConnectData` of RTD Server does not get called.

Is there anyway of getting ConnectData called in such a situation where parameters aren t changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I call Application.CalculateFull from Visual Basic. I have found that triggers the RTD function being called again. I then have a button on the spreadsheet which calls a macro that contains Application.CalculateFull. Anytime I want to restart, I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

An RTD topic is created for each unique combination of topic parameters of the RTD function. When you re-enter the same function call, the RDF function is called but it does not create a new topic.

ConnectData is called only when a new topic is created.

That means if you enter the same RTD function call in multiple cells, they will all share the same RTD topic. ConnectData will only be called once.